# Frequency of the matched string in solr

Tags: pdf, solr, apache-tika

I am indexing pdfs in my application. I want to show the frequency of the searched string in each pdf. I am using debugQuery=true and parsing the debug result. I am setting debug.explain.structured=true.

For e.g: 
Input-foo then it will list all the pdfs in which this foo occurs.
Output-cover.pdf 2 matches found(Just an example)

This works fine but the situation when I search for multiple words.
Input- foo AND bar

The format of the debug result changes. Ok fine, I parsed this format also but its giving the frequency of only foo but nor bar.

Can anybody please tell me how to get the frequency of the searched words. I have checked termfrequency but we cant give multiple words there also.

Answer (score 0):

What about using highlighting for that? It will create an entry per match in a doc

Comment: I am using dismax query parser also so If I search for "solr search" then solr is highlighting solr and search separately so my counts will be doubled If I count them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use facets for this query.It will return you the counts for that facet as well.

Comment: Its not coming since I am indexing pdfs so a column text has the whole pdf indexed. If we can do then can you tell me how..thanks!